# Issue with Thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I bought and installed a Trueway thermostat before 2 years. It was working well for the past years. But then a twist! the thermostat started to go nuts, the tempeature would race over 60 degree, even though I had set it 40 degree or bellow!! Do you know what is the problem? and also I would to know about the normal life period of a thermostat.

Comment: Have you tried replacing/troubleshooting the thermostat to see if it's actually the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Does your thermostat take batteries? The thermostat in my house takes a standard AA battery. When the battery got old, the thermostat went nuts. If it does take a battery, it's probably about due for a replacement.